# how to create XX number of users in mongoDB using jmeter and use these users to test login/authorization performance scenarios

Tags: jmeter

We are using MongoDB and need to create n users to test the performance of login scenarios by passing these users in JMeter, I can use CSV file to pass username/password values however for this I need to first create 500 users in DB. I saw some info on the net saying to use MongoDB script to generate data but this is Depreciated.

Please suggest how can I create these users. 
how to create XX number of users in MongoDB using JMeter and use these users to test login/authorization performance scenarios.
[image: MongoDB config]
[image: MongoDB script]

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB test elements were marked as "deprecated" [due to low interest of the users in this functionality](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58772), however they still can be used.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   not_in_menu=
   ```

   this way you will be able to restore the access to deprecated test elements via JMeter GUI
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. You should now see and use [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config) and [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script) test elements to establish MongoDB Connection and execute arbitrary queries.

See [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) article for detailed information on working with MongoDB with JMeter.

Comment: Able to get MongoDB Script after using 'not_in_menu=' in user.properties file and followed steps as provided in the given article. However the thread group shows as started but not getting results (used tried by giving username/pwd also in the script). Please suggest. Added screen shots in the original post.